# Problem in proof for : Product of any three consecutive integers is a multiple of 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory

From a book, I have got proof as follows, that otherwise I would have solved using just logic that any consecutive $3$ values have one and only one value in equivalence class $\equiv 0\pmod 3$, and have difficulty in understanding. I have divided the given proof into two sequential parts, and hope that the first part's understanding will be enough:

Part (i) : Since any integer can be written in the form $3n \text{ or } 3n\pm 1$, the difference of two integers of the same form is a multiple of $3$, and therefore not less than $3$.

Part (ii) : But the difference of any two of three consecutive integers is less than $3$, so that the three consecutive integers are respectively of the above three forms, among which one is of the form $3n$, that is, a multiple of $3$.

---

In Part (i), the problem lies in logic, as for given form of two integers as : $3n, 3n + 1$, the difference is $-1$ and is less than $3$, as the value of $n$ has to be the same.

Comment: None of the answer there is of this specific form.

Comment: I don't know how any answer 'there' is of the stated form. I feel 'duplicate' tag is wrong, as solution matters here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here "difference" means "absolute difference". Let $x$ and $y$ be two distinct integers of same form; then $x = 3n + r$ and $y = 3m + r$, for some integers $n$ and $m$, and $r = 0, 1$ or $2$.

Then $x - y = 3(n - m$), and $n- m$ cannot be $0$ as the integers are distinct. Hence the absolute difference between $x$ an $y$ will never be less than $3$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).